# compress image before insert it to the database

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i have table in database(SQL server) contain image column, how to compress the image before insert it to the database?
or if there any solution for what i need to do i will be Glad, this what i need:
i'm making a small program for rent shops, so the user will print contracts and after the contract printed and signed the user want to store it again so he can retrieve it any time. i'm using image column to allow the user to have a copy for the contract as image but the problem is that the contracts is 2 pages so for the one contract i need 2 image and this take a lot of space.
is there any way to do it deferment. i'm using a server to feed all computers connected to the program.

this is the code to insert image:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim fName As String
    fName = imagepath
    If File.Exists(fName) Then

        Dim content As Byte() = ImageToStream(fName)
        'فحص الاتصال بقاعدة البيانات
        If SQL.conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            SQL.conn.Close()
        End If
        SQL.conn.Open()


        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into test (image) values(@image)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", (content))


        cmd.Connection = SQL.conn
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        SQL.conn.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox(fName & " الصورة المختارة ليست موجودة او غير صالحة  ", vbCritical, "حصل خطأ")
    End If
End Sub

Dim imagepath As String
Dim myStream As IO.Stream = Nothing
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
    'Set the Filter.
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png"
    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                imagepath = openFileDialog1.FileName

            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open.
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myStream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    Else
        openFileDialog1.FileName = Nothing
        Return
    End If
End Sub
Private Function ImageToStream(ByVal fileName As String) As Byte()
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
tryagain:
    Try
        Dim image As New Bitmap(fileName)
        image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Catch ex As Exception
        GoTo tryagain
    End Try

    Return stream.ToArray()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest compressing the images. Unfortunately, this would probably have little affect on many of the more common image formats (such as Jpeg) as they are already compressed.

You could adjust the quality to the minimum (whilst still being a readable image) at the time the images are uploaded. But I would suggest doing this at the time they are scanned in. That way each one could be viewed to see that it is still readable.